# Classes are also objects in objective-c, how does this differ from C#?

Tags: c#, objective-c

Classes are also objects in objective-c, how does this differ from C#? (if it does).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the *definition* of the class is also an object? In .NET, every class/struct/etc has an associated (read-only) `Type` object that provides metadata for the type, such as listing the fields/properties/methods etc. Is that what you meant?

You can obtain the `Type` in several ways; for example:

```
Type type = typeof(Customer); // from the type itself
```

or from an instance:

```
Type type = someObj.GetType(); // from an instance
```

All *instances* of a class are (by definition) objects.